# Whats is a template image in segmentation problem

Tags: image-processing

I'm actually reading a paper about brain segmentation but i don't understand whats is an 'Template image', here a part if the paper:

"*We denote T a template image and S its segmentation
(obtained manually or semi-manually). We also suppose that
T is registered on image I to propagate the segmentation S
on I. As the boundaries of the regions of interest in I and
T are not obvious everywhere in our images, we propose
in this paper a new registration algorithm which strongly
constrains the deformations of T with deformations learned
by registering the segmentation of T on the segmented
training images $I_n$, n ∈ [1, · · · , N]*.
"

Thanks u

Comment: Do u think it is maths question?

Comment: Yeah it's an applied maths question from a maths journal paper